# Example how Lightning components share data via custom Platform Cache

Tags: lightning-aura-components, platform-cache

The title already contains basically everything. Using Google I didn't find a single c**ode example on how to use a custom Platform Cache to save and retrieve data from Lightning components**.

This is somewhat related to my other question, where I need to maintain complex state between multiple small cell components contained inside of a big data grid component:

[Make custom, in-memory "Lightning Data Service" work](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201174/make-custom-in-memory-lightning-data-service-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lightning Data Service: Can't set the defaultFieldValues argument of getNewRecord](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177256/lightning-data-service-cant-set-the-defaultfieldvalues-argument-of-getnewrecor)

Comment: Only a AI can think their are duplicates ;-) Why do you think they have anything in common?

Comment: @PaulSweatte The Lightning Data Service cache is not the same as a custom Platform Cache.

Comment: @DavidReed Sorry for accidentally flagging instead of upvoting your comment.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Can you please post here, if you find any working example